# kbd debe ser usado solo para formato de teclas

Tags: discusión, formato

Recientemente he tenido una [edición en una respuesta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/4958/revisions) indicando:

> kbd debe ser usado solo para formato de teclas.

Hasta ahora no había tenido jamás problema alguno en usar `kbd` para resaltar enlaces a los ejemplos de código online, he usado esa etiqueta varias veces en Stack Overflow en Inglés con ese objetivo sin que nadie haya considerado jamás su uso como incorrecto (de hecho, es una costumbre bastante extendida).

No creo que ese uso (estético) sea incorrecto, tampoco creo que las normas de cada una de las páginas deba variar según el idioma.

¿Existe alguna postura oficial al respecto?

Comment: Yo hice la edición y estoy de acuerdo con @rnd, y también estoy de acuerdo con el hecho de que si no estás de acuerdo con mi edición tienes el derecho a revertirla y no argumentaré más, sin embargo me parece que lo más saludable es utilizar cada formato para lo que fue creado en cada caso.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no me molesta la edición, puede quedarse tal cuál está. Sin embargo a mi *personalmente* me gusta más `kbd` para poner el enlace de ejemplo de código pues:
1) Resalta el enlace más que el subrayado y cambio de color.
2) No oculta que es clickable, pues se asemeja a un botón de un formulario.

Comment: Podría decirse que se trata de una de tantas norma no escritas relacionada. Cada profesión/gremio/comunidad tiene las suyas. Algunos le llaman cultura, educación, "usos y costumbres", "sentido común", etc. y es uno de los elementos de identidad y cohesión. En este caso como varios lo han mencionado más de algo rígido se trata de un "uso preferido".

Comment: @Rubén entonces seguiré mi propio criterio, omitir `kbd` en es.stackoveflow y seguir usándolo en stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 9):

**no** *hay* NoRMAs ob*Li*gat**Ori**as <strike>de</strike> <kbd>formato</kbd>, pero `tiene`

> sentido

*s**e**g**u**iR* <kbd>algunos</kbd> linea**miento**s p*AR*a q**U**e una **pub**LICA**ción** `sea` más **fác**il de leer. ... ***o NO?***

---

Hablando en serio, creo este es un tema muy abierto a opiniones, pero si existe cierta posición de la comunidad al respecto: @animuson♦ en [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181795/268782), opina que usando `<kbd>` se hace mas difícil saber de golpe de vista si es un link clickable. Yo también opino asi, pero tu lo ves diferente.

La cosa es que ..

### **`<kbd></kbd>` fue pensado para teclas, no para links.**

Y por ello, tiene ese *significado*, si tu le das otro significado, pues te arriesgas un poco mas a que no se entienda bien (digamos, un 1% mas, despreciable)

> - <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> Teclas (pues parece un botón)
> - [Enlaces](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/489/25): Para Los vínculos hay algo especial, en el sitio principal se ve azul, como cualquier link en internet.

De cualquier forma, en mi opinion, cada uno puede hacerlo como quiera, y puede revertirlo si no esta de acuerdo con la estética de una edición hecha por un tercero. Pero se han dado ciertos nombres a los estilos para *intentar* que mantengamos un formato/estilo común a lo largo del sitio.

Yo prefiero dejar `<kbd/>` para las teclas.... pero voy a insistir que estas en todo tu derecho de revertir la edición, pues eres dueño de crear tu propio estilo.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. StackOverflow hace un gran esfuerzo para que el sitio tenga contenido de calidad y este es un problema se puede generalizar sobre todo en los usuarios nuevos que pueden hacer mal uso de él y argumentarán que lo vieron en otras partes del sitio.

Comment: Desde un punto de vista de la web semántica, `<kbd>` debería ser solo para teclas o en general cosas relacionadas con un teclado (al fin y al cabo, `kbd` viene de *keyboard*). Y se supone que somos buenos programadores, así que...